# How does linux kernel Makefile understands .config?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration, make

How does linux kernel Makefile understands .config? Does it have a parser of defconfig file? It has to produce a lot of #defines for each enabled option from defconfig and also maintain a lot of minor Makefiles which are compiled or not, based on directives in .config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of the `.config` file is compatible with make; for example a line like `CONFIG_CRC16=m` sets the make variable `CONFIG_CRC16` to the value `m`. It's parsed by make and included indirectly in the toplevel `Makefile`:

- `Makefile` contains `-include include/config/auto.conf`
- `include/config/auto.conf` is built by recursively calling the toplevel `Makefile` on the `silentoldconfig` target.

Conditional compilation of files is done mostly by playing with target names: makefiles include rules like

```
obj-$(CONFIG_CRC16) += crc16.o
```

The target `obj-y` thus builds all objects that are enabled as built-ins by a configuration option, and `obj-m` builds all objects that are enabled as modules. There are also conditional directives in the makefiles for more complex cases.

For conditional compilation in the C language, C source files include `include/generated/autoconf.h` which contains lines like `#define CONFIG_CRC16_MODULE 1`. This file is generated from `include/config/auto.conf` by the programs invoked by the `xxxconfig` targets (`scripts/kconfig/conf` for batch targets like `oldconfig`, `scripts/kconfig/qconf` for `xconfig`, etc.); the source code for that is `scripts/kconfig/confdata.c` which does some very simple text processing.

Comment: +1. The only trickiness really is the stuff in the top-level `Makefile` designed to ensure that all the `config` targets are run before any of the `build` targets.